# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/DocumentFactory

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm getting this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/DocumentFactory
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook.<clinit>(CTWorkbook.java:22)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:475)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:232)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:226)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:214)
    at com.leanapps.businesslayer.ejb.importparticipants.helper.ImportParticipantsHelper.determineExcelWorkbook(ImportParticipantsHelper.java:307)
    at com.leanapp
```

*****while upgrading the POI to 5.2.1 from 4*****

My POM looks like

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>${poi.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-lite</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>${poi.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-lite</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
                <version>${poi.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-lite</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>

                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

My xml bean version 3.1.0
Any suggestions please? I'm using same version of POI for excluding old version adding dependecy in excusion section

expected abel to download the excel
actual:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/DocumentFactory     at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook.<clinit>(CTWorkbook.java:22)  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:475)
```

Comment: "My xml bean version 3.1.0": Why? And how? `<dependency<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId><version>5.2.1</version></dependency>` should pull `org.apache.xmlbeans » xmlbeans 5.0.3` and that is what is needed.

Comment: Hi Axel, Thank you for qucick response but when i changed  xml bean version to 5.0.3  i'm getting compilation issues as below ******builder/xml/ProfitSharingYieldTableDocument.java:[492,259] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class XMLStreamException
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream*******

Comment: hi @AxelRichter  i'm getting  generated class as" deprecated xmlInputStream" below cod eis for reference  `**  /** @deprecated {@link org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream} */
        public static com.leanapps.life.product.builder.xml.CostClass parse(org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream xis) throws org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException, org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLStreamException {
          return (com.leanapps.life.product.builder.xml.CostClass) org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getContextTypeLoader().parse( xis, type, null ); }`

Comment: What is `com.leanapps.life.product.builder.xml.CostClass`? What is `ProfitSharingYieldTableDocument.java` code lines 492 and 259? Seems your other libraries does not fit to Apache POI 5 as they need XMLBeans 3 while Apache POI 5 needs XMLBeans 5 now. Update all to last versions.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).